# Twilio :(Error: 63015) Channel Sandbox can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-chat

```
Twilio :(Error: 63015) Channel Sandbox can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox.
```

How can I send a message to a recipient without adding them to sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

They must have joined the sandbox unless you apply and are approved for your own WhatsApp number, detailed below.

[How Can I Get my Own WhatsApp Twilio Number for Use in Production?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017771714-How-Can-I-Get-my-Own-WhatsApp-Twilio-Number-for-Use-in-Production-)